# No muestra un momento en el If else para mostrar 3 tipos de momentos

Tags: java, condiciones, else

Buenas tardes estimada comunidad, tengo un problema en el momento de mostrar un momento, en un primer momento, se escoge la especialidad la cual se muestra con `escoge_especialidad`, en un segundo momento el mismo individuo hace un cambio y debe mostrarse pero para pacientes nuevos y debe mostrar el jsp `cambio_especialidad.jsp` pero me muestra el `cambio_especialidad2.jsp`, el cual me muestra pero de pacientes antiguos, la validación en la BD esta bien, el problema es en el if else pero no logro identificarlo, por favor su ayuda comunidad seria de mucho, gracias!!

while (rs.next()){

```
                        fila=new AlumnoBean();
                        fila.setCodcli(rs.getString(1));
                        fila.setNombre(rs.getString(2));
                        fila.setApepat(rs.getString(3));
                        fila.setApemat(rs.getString(4));
                        System.out.println(" simpleil"+fila.getCodcli()); 
                        misession.setAttribute("sesion", fila);
                                            
                        
                        System.out.println(fila.getNombre());
                     variable=fila.getNombre();
                       System.out.println("sale prodecure");
                        }
                                            
                         if (variable.equals("ESPECIALIDAD ANTIGUO")) {                 
                               
                            request.setAttribute("b", fila);
                            RequestDispatcher rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/cambio_especialidad2.jsp");
                            rd.forward((ServletRequest)request, (ServletResponse)response);
                            
                              
                                 }                 
                             else {     
                                    if (variable.equals("ESPECIALIDAD NUEVO")) {                    
                                                      
                            request.setAttribute("b", fila);
                            RequestDispatcher rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/cambio_especialidad.jsp");
                            rd.forward((ServletRequest)request, (ServletResponse)response);
                            
                                                        } 
                                    if (variable.equals("SIN ESPECIALIDAD")) {                  
                                                          
                            request.setAttribute("b", fila);
                            RequestDispatcher rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/escoge_especialidad.jsp");
                            rd.forward((ServletRequest)request, (ServletResponse)response);
                                    }
                            request.setAttribute("b", fila);
                            RequestDispatcher rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login_especialidad.jsp");
                            rd.forward((ServletRequest)request, (ServletResponse)response);
                                             
                                    }
                        }
                         
                         else {
                                             String v="Usuario o Clave incorrecta";
                                            request.setAttribute("ir", v);
                                           RequestDispatcher rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login_especialidad.jsp");
                                           rd.forward((ServletRequest)request, (ServletResponse)response);
                                           
                                        }
                                  
                                  
                              
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                salida.print(e.getMessage());
                            }       
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Trate de ordenar tu codigo y sobran llaves.. sera ese el problema? usa el boton editar y fijate que el codigo no se puede ordenar bien por ese motivo...

Comment: ¿podrías acomodar el código? Otra cosa, al momento de depurar, ¿Qué sucede con el if? Otra cosa, ¿Ya probaste haciendo `if (especialidad) { viejos } else if (especialidad) { nuevos} else { lo que sea }`?

Comment: Gracias gbianchi pero no logro identificar las llaves que sobran.....por otro lado Franqo Blasamo lo que propones ya esta plasmado en el código, gracias. y aun me sigue mostrando cuando quiero hacer un cambio en el momento del nuevo me sale el jsp del antiguo que es camio_especialidad2.jsp

Comment: El código de la publicación tiene muchos errores, tal como plantea @gbianchi. Por favor leer [mcve]. Tu código no es reproducible. Saludos